# React parent to scroll down after all children are rendered

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, render, use-effect

I have a pretty simple chat logic where I initially fetch the history from the database and then conditionally render all the children based on the content in the database. Ongoing I am then receiving messages via a WebSocket connection.

Now I would like to scroll to the bottom of the chat:

- when the initial content is loaded **AND** rendered (each message is potentially a different child)
- when a new message comes in **AND** is rendered

I tried something along the lines of

```
const Message = ({data}) => {
    return **lazily loaded component**
}


const Container = () => {
    const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

    const [chatData,SetChatData] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        // fetch and set data

        // initialize socket connection
    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (messagesEndRef.current) {
                scrollToEnd();
            }
        }, 500);
    }, []);

    return 
    (<>
        <div>
            {chatData.map(message => <Message data={message} key={message._id})/>}
        <div>
        <div id="messagesEndRef" style={{ float: 'left', clear: 'both' }} ref={messagesEndRef}></div>
    </>
}
```

However, the problem here is that the timeout is a poor man's trick, as oftentimes not all the children will be rendered and thus the scroll ends up being somewhere in the middle, but nowhere near the end.

Any idea how to go about that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
useEffect(() => {
        scrollToEnd();
    },[chatData])
```

It listens to every changes of the state `chatData`.

Comment: Thx for the feedback, but that does not work, as the data arrives way before the children are rendered.